Is there a way to make paypal payments work on the registration page of shopware?
I am trying to make a single page for customer registration and order confirmation, meaning that as soon as a customer registers in the /checkout/register page, instead of redirecting him to the /checkout/confirm page, his order will be placed automatically because the payments selection and the shipments selection have been moved directly to the /checkout/register page see this screenshot ().
As you can see the radio boxes have been moved directly into the page, the vorkasse payment for example works fine because i was able to work on it on my local environment and test everything out, so i have been able to mimic the behavior of the /checkout/confirm page and make it work directly without redirection. Unfortunately, i am having issues with paypal and i do not know what to do exactly because the paypal plugin does not work correctly on localhost see these screenshots (, ).
So i am actually unable to see what is going wrong here, but the paypal plugin is stuck and does not accept any payments, the first thing that happens as soon as i try is an error that can be seen in the devtools when paypal makes a request followed by others, see this screenshot ().
Also the paypal option (Credit Cards) which should display the form to the customer to enter his/her details is not working properly, no form displayed.
there are probably some functions in the background that are throwing exceptions but as i said i cannot really test in on my local, if there is a way to do so please let me know.
P.S: i do not have access to many development tools on our server like xdebug for example.
in the admin panel the order has already been created but the payment status is unconfirmed
and paypal is waiting for a customer action 
but the customer does not know that as no action was prompted for him in the storefront.
here is the twig code in the src/Resources/views/storefront/component/account/register.html.twig which extends the payment and shipping methods
{% block page_checkout_confirm_payment %}
            <div class="col-md-6 confirm-payment">
                {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-payment.html.twig' %}
            </div>
        {% endblock %}


        {% block page_checkout_confirm_shipping %}
            {% set PHYSICAL_STATE = constant('Shopware\\Core\\Content\\Product\\State::IS_PHYSICAL') %}
            {% if page.cart.lineItems.hasLineItemWithState(PHYSICAL_STATE) %}
                <div class="col-md-6 confirm-shipping">
                    {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/page/checkout/confirm/confirm-shipping.html.twig' %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}


            <div class="confirm-tos">
                <div class="card checkout-card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_header %}
                            <div class="card-title">
                                {{ "checkout.confirmTermsHeader"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice %}
                            <p
                                class="revocation-notice">
                                {# @deprecated tag:v6.6.0 - Block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice_link is deprecated. Use outer block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice instead. #}
                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_revocation_notice_link %}
                                    {{ "checkout.confirmRevocationNotice"|trans({
                                    '%url%': path('frontend.cms.page', { id: config('core.basicInformation.revocationPage') })
                                })|raw }}
                                {% endblock %}
                            </p>
                        {% endblock %}

                        {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control %}
                            <div class="ps-0 form-check">
                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_checkbox %}
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="d-none checkout-confirm-tos-checkbox form-check-input" required="required" id="tos" checked="checked" form="confirmOrderForm" name="tos">
                                {% endblock %}

                                {% block page_checkout_confirm_tos_control_label %}
                                    <label for="tos" class="checkout-confirm-tos-label custom-control-label">
                                        {{ "checkout.confirmTermsText"|trans({
                                        '%url%': path('frontend.cms.page', { id: config('core.basicInformation.tosPage') })
                                    })|raw }}
                                    </label>
                                {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <form
                id="confirmOrderForm" action="/checkout/order" data-form-preserver="true" data-form-submit-loader="true" data-form-add-history="true" data-form-add-history-options="{&quot;entries&quot;:[{&quot;state&quot;:[],&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Orders&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;\/account\/order&quot;}]}" method="post"><!-- BLOCK END page_checkout_confirm_form_submit -->
            </form>
            <div class="register-submit d-grid col-md-6 offset-md-6">
                <button id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" form="registerForm">
                    {{ "account.registerSubmit"|trans|sw_sanitize }}
                </button>
            </div>
        {% endblock %}


It is not possible for a site that is only accessible on localhost to receive webhooks.
